# Php get subjectAltName from csr

Tags: php-openssl, subject-alternative-name

Good evening my friend
I generated san csr via openssl function using php. But i cant get subjectAltName. Please How can i extract subjetAltName from csr?

```
shell_exec('openssl req -noout -text -in'. $csr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
$r = shell_exec('openssl req -noout -text -in '. $csr)
                                             ^- a space here!
```

for my test however openssl did not print a Subject Alt Name, so i'll show how to get the Subject:

```
preg_match('/Subject:\s*(.*)\n/', $r, $matches);
$subject = $matches[1];
```